# php_value enable in custom country or ip

Tags: php, ip

I want use php_value  in custom ip or country

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx enable
<IfDefine enable>
php_value include_path ".:/path"
</IfDefine>
```

but not work

Comment: `ifdefine` has nothing to do with apache env vars: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#ifdefine You want just [`<if>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#if)

Comment: <if> not work.another way?

Comment: <If> is Apache 2.4 and later only